# mx 1100 bluetooth adaptor replacement with software

Tags: mouse, bluetooth

is it possible to develop software which uses built in laptop bluetooth to receive mouse signals without bluetooth adaptop that mx 1100 mouse has ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MX 1100 is not a Bluetooth mouse. The USB receiver is to receive the proprietary wireless signals transmitted by the mouse. As a result, you cannot use your laptop's built-in Bluetooth hardware with that mouse.

If you purchase a Bluetooth mouse (like the Logitech V470 or the Apple Magic Mouse), you can (and should) use your laptop's built-in Bluetooth receiver; if a USB Bluetooth receiver comes with your Bluetooth mouse, you can set it aside and not use it.

Comment: Any time! I'll upvote your question; once you have 15 reputation, upvote my reply if you like it (in addition to accepting it, which you already did).